# Regular expression matching an infinite pattern

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern that will be used in a C program to match following pattern:

• Contains at least one digit

• If there are multiple digits, they have to be separated by a space

Thus following are valid (Note that the pattern isn't restricted and can contain any amount of digits as long as they are separated by a space):

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
```

And these are invalid:

```
0  
0 00
0 12 1 0
 0 
 0
0 
00
0 1
```

I am kind of new to regex so my attempts have not resulted to the correct answer. My attempts have matched on the invalid strings as well, but here's what I've tried:

```
^(([0-9])(\s))+||([0-9])$
```

Comment: Do you mean `^[0-9]( +[0-9])*$`?

Comment: Why are `0` and `0 1` both valid and invalid? Or do you mean all the lines in the the valid example count as one string?

Comment: @Jerry looks like those invalid entries have extra spaces afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an optional repeating non capturing group which start with a space:

```
^\d(?: \d)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bupy9S/1)

- `^` Start of string
- `\d` match a digit (or use `[0-9]`)
- `(?: \d)*` Non capturing group to match a space followed by a digit and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string.

If the non capturing group is not supported, you could use:

```
^[0-9]( [0-9])*$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanted to match the four partterns, you could use | to set different conditions.

```
^\d$|^\d\s\d$|^\d\s\d\s\d$|^\d\s\d\s\d\s\d$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dculuv/1)

- `^`  position the at start of a line
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `$` position at the end of a line

Comment: This pattern is limited to a numbered amount of digits

Comment: ^\d( \d)*  should work. I don't know why somebody add non-capturing group.

Comment: Non capture group makes the matching faster because no additional memory has to be allocated to store the match(es)