# Start (^) and end ($) anchors not working

Tags: c, regex, posix

Basically I'm using following pattern in my C program (See [Regular expression matching an infinite pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54900643/6946169)):

```
^[0-9]( [0-9])*$
```

with following code:

```
char *pattern = "^[0-9]( [0-9])*$";
regex_t regexCompiled;
int rc = regcomp(&regexCompiled, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
if (rc != 0) {
    char msgbuf[100];
    regerror(rc, &regexCompiled, msgbuf, sizeof (msgbuf));
    fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (regexec(&regexCompiled, "0 1", 0, NULL, REG_EXTENDED) == 0) {
    printf("Valid\n");
} else {
    printf("Invalid\n");
}
```

Where I exec against the string "0 1", which is valid for the pattern and it's not working. The '^' and '$' are not functioning. Why is that? and how can I make it work?

Comment: Only `regcomp` needs `REG_EXTENDED`. Then use `regexec(&regexCompiled, input, 0, NULL, 0)`

Comment: You can see [it works well](https://ideone.com/e8nlYl). You must have another issue somewhere.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, after some time looking at the code, I noticed that I was missed a symbol in my pattern.

Comment: best question ever. saved me another week of research, trial and error <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `REG_EXTENDED` to `regexec()`, that's not a valid flag for that call.

[The manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp) says:

> eflags may be the bitwise-or of one or both of `REG_NOTBOL` and `REG_NOTEOL` which cause changes in matching behavior described below.

Probably the actual value of `REG_EXTENDED` matches one of those.

Changing the code to pass `0` as the final argument to `regexec()` makes it match.

Comment: I changed to following and it does not work. Removing REG_EXTENDED does not work at all:
int rc = regcomp(&regexCompiled, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
regexec(&regexCompiled, "0 1", 0, NULL, 0)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you provide full code in separate answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I put a 0 on ct_flags argument for regexec and it didn't work. I tried that with and without REG_EXTENDED supplied as a flag to regcomp. Followed what was described as the solution and it's not working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Alright, I've added the edits in main post.